# How to condense/simplify this block of code that extracts data from a csv file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have this code which extracts data from a csv file and then reformats it so that it can be compared with another data set:

```
def dataExtract
  dates = File.open(@filename_data).read.scan /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/
  data_extracted = []
  index = 0
  dates.each do |date|
    inbound_row = @data[4+(11*index)]
    outbound_row = @data[6+(11*index)]
    data_extracted.push [date, '4001', (inbound_row[1].gsub(/\,/,"").to_i + inbound_row[2].gsub(/\,/,"").to_i).to_s, 'AI', 'INBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '4090', inbound_row[3].gsub(/\,/,""), 'AI', 'INBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '1139', inbound_row[4].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'INBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '1158', inbound_row[5].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'INBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '4055', outbound_row[1].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU PLUS', 'OUTBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '4055', outbound_row[2].gsub(/\,/,""), 'AR', 'OUTBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '1139', outbound_row[4].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'OUTBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '1158', outbound_row[5].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'OUTBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '4091', outbound_row[3].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'OUTBOUND']
    index += 1
  end
  return data_extracted   
end
```

And here is a sample of the csv data (this is for one day. For multiple days there are chunks like this with an empty space inbetween them):

```
Date,BLOCK,,Wood,Miscellaneous,,Totals,MO
Monday,4055-RU,4055-AR,4091,1139,1158,,100
11/4/15,C Sort,B,C,iGPS,PECO,,
Starting,714,228,858,82,129,"2,011",
Sorted,"2,738",190,"1,110",144,228,"4,410",
Subtotal 1,"3,452",418,"1,968",226,357,"6,421",
Shipped,"2,700",0,"1,865",0,0,"4,565",
,752,418,103,226,357,"1,856",
Physical,752,418,103,226,357,"1,856",
Variance,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

The only data being used in this csv file (besides the dates) are the sorted and shipped rows. Anyways, like I said, this works, it just isn't very pretty. Is there a better way to execute the dates.each block since there is repeated info (date is in each array + inbound/outbound)?

Comment: Don't know what you want to achieve... May be replacing your `date_extracted` array by 2 arrays called  `inbound` and `outbound`, is a start.

Comment: if your first row contains the column headers, then every column should have one. It's really not important but looks better and might come handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe simpler, maybe not - but hopefully enough to give you an idea on how to continue to improve it.

```
data_extracted = []

inbound_data_set = [['4090',3,'AI'],['1139',4,'RU STANDRD'],['1158',5,'RU STANDRD']]
outbound_data_set = [['4055',1,'RU PLUS'],['4055',2,'AR'],['1139',4,'RU STANDRD'],['1158',5,'RU STANDRD'],['4091',3,'RU STANDRD']]

dates.each_with_index do |date,index|
  inbound_row = @data[4+(11*index)]
  outbound_row = @data[6+(11*index)]
  # this one stays as it's much different
  data_extracted << [date, '4001', (inbound_row[1].gsub(/\,/,"").to_i + inbound_row[2].gsub(/\,/,"").to_i).to_s, 'AI', 'INBOUND']
  inbound_data_set.each do |num,idx,type|
    data_extracted << [date, num, (inbound_row[idx].gsub(/\,/,"")), type, 'INBOUND']
  end
  outbound_data_set.each do |num,idx,type|
    data_extracted << [date, num, (outbound_row[idx].gsub(/\,/,"")), type, 'OUTBOUND']
  end
end
```

EDIT: the code was missing a ')' on (inbound_row[idx].gsub(/\,/,"")) and (outbound_row[idx].gsub(/\,/,"")).

Comment: Thank you! this is the kind of reduction/simplification I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Replace `File.open(filename).read` with `File.read(filename)`, and use `each_with_index` rather than `index += 1`, and get rid of the redundant `return` at the end, and use `snake_case` for method names:

```
def data_extract
  dates = File.read(@filename_data).scan /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/
  data_extracted = []
  dates.each_with_index do |date, index|
    inbound_row = @data[4+(11*index)]
    outbound_row = @data[6+(11*index)]
    data_extracted.push [date, '4001', (inbound_row[1].gsub(/\,/,"").to_i + inbound_row[2].gsub(/\,/,"").to_i).to_s, 'AI', 'INBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '4090', inbound_row[3].gsub(/\,/,""), 'AI', 'INBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '1139', inbound_row[4].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'INBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '1158', inbound_row[5].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'INBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '4055', outbound_row[1].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU PLUS', 'OUTBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '4055', outbound_row[2].gsub(/\,/,""), 'AR', 'OUTBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '1139', outbound_row[4].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'OUTBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '1158', outbound_row[5].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'OUTBOUND']
    data_extracted.push [date, '4091', outbound_row[3].gsub(/\,/,""), 'RU STANDRD', 'OUTBOUND']
  end
  data_extracted   
end
```